# what's the difference between assign and bound when talking about variable?

Tags: python, variables, assign

Except from http://www.stavros.io/tutorials/python/

```
# This swaps the variables in one line(!).
# It doesn't violate strong typing because values aren't
# actually being assigned, but new objects are bound to
# the old names.
>>> myvar, mystring = mystring, myvar
```

I don't understand the point he is making.

Answer (score 0):

He means to say the two variables are *essentially* swapped without knowing their types or explicitly using an intermediate variable as you normally would. A weakly-typed swap looks like this:

```
temp = A
A = B
B = temp
```

A previously-unitialized temporary variable `temp` must be created in order to perform the swap. However, because no type is specified when `temp` is first created, it violates strong typing. Here is a strongly-typed swap:

```
int temp = A
A = B
B = temp
```

A swap like `A, B = B, A` does not violate strong typing because an intermediate variable doesn't need to be explicitly defined with or without a type. It's simply an assignment operation, and a basic assignment operation is always ambiguously typed (aka: `A = B` is the same regardless of whether you are using a strong-typed language or a weak-typed one).

Answer (score 0):

An assignment like `a=1` , conceptually Python will perform three distinct steps to carry out the request.

1.Create an object to represent the value `1`

2.Create the variable `a`.

3.Link(or bound as in the link) the variable `a` to new object `1`.

In your case, the statement

`myvar, mystring = mystring, myvar`

will change the variable-object bound relationship.